# Subsetting Date Lists

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have two DatetimeIndex (indices?) and this is what I am trying to do:

```
new_dates_to_add = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-21', '2020-01-22', '2020-01-23', '2020-01-24'])
old_dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-22', '2020-01-24'])
new_dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-21', '2020-01-23'])
```

So new_dates contains the items in `new_dates_to_add` that are not in old_dates.

I tried a simple loop, where I made them both lists, then loop over them, but received the error `'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable`

```
list_b = list(new_dates_to_add)
list_a = list(old_dates)
new_dates = [x for x in list_b if x[0] in list_a]
```

I can see that `old_dates` are in `new_dates_to_add` with `set(old_dates).issubset(new_dates_to_add)`, but not how to access the dates in `new_dates_to_add` that are not in `old_dates`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of working with dates, I converted them into strings first, then was able to see if items were or were not in the required list.

```
new_dates_to_add = [datetime.strftime(x, "%Y-%m-%d") for x in new_dates_to_add]
old_dates = [datetime.strftime(x, "%Y-%m-%d") for x in old_dates]
new_dates = [x for x in new_dates if x not in old_dates]
```